# Firebase IOS UTM Install Tracking

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using firebase analytics to track installations on both android and ios. This work fines but I can't get the UTM campaign from IOS Installations. I'm using the following link to generate Android campaigns:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142?hl=en

The problem is that the IOS Url builder requires an parameter "GA-ID" in format "UA-XXXX-Y". We are using Firebase Analytics and it don't have this value, only the stream id.

How can I track campaign installs on IOS with Firebase Analytics in the best way?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Google's Account Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/)

You'll be able to see the apps you've set up and there's a `Property (Tracking id)` field, which contains the `UA-XXXXXX` ID that you need.

[image]

Comment: We are using other type of property, one that is integrated with Firebase Analytics. So we don't have a Tracking ID, only Property ID and Stream IDs.

Comment: Looking at GA4 requests in the browser, it could be Stream ID.